# Replace values from non-identical columns in other dataframe

Tags: python

I have two dataframes and I need to replace values in df1 from df2. I get the error: "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"

```
df1['Color']=np.where(df1['Value']==df2['Old_Value'], df2['New_Color'],df1['Color'])
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df1.Color.update(df1.Value.map(df2.set_index('Old_Value').New_Color))`